'Volatility' of electric charge on a balloon
It is well-known that if a charged balloon touches an electroscope, some charge is transferred. When the balloon is removed, the electroscope keeps that charge. But actually the balloon does not need to touch the electroscope, even at a distance of 5 cm it transfers charge, through the air, to the electroscope. The charge remains on the electroscope after removing the balloon. A charged balloon seems to be somewhat better at this than say, a charged pvc pipe, or a charged metal surface.
What is the mechanism for this charge 'volatility' on the surface of an object. Does the charge actually jump from the balloon to the electroscope; is it irreversible; do air molecules play a role? Would it be the same in vacuum?

Vacuum is a much better insulator than air, particularly humid air. But even in vacuum you can have corona currents.
